# How to find binding element of AngularJS in selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I have a following element in the webpage:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here" class="ng-valid  ng-dirty">
    </input>
    <hr>
    <h1 class="ng-binding">Hello !</h1>
```

How can i access the "ng-binding" element in selenium:

```
    driver.findElement(By.className("ng-binding{{???}}"));
```

Comment: Why not use protractor for testing AngularJS ?

Answer (score -1):

I also think you can use e2e test in your App.

Comment: There some documentation for e2e test, you can read it.
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/guide/e2e-testing